# Understanding the code for std::move()

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I really want to understand the intrinsic details of the std::move() function.

The code for std::move() as stated here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html#Move_Semantics.

```
template <class T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type&&
move(T&& a)
{
    return a;
}
```

Why does this code return a rvalue reference? The parameter is a type T rvalue reference. Does `a` evaluate to the object pointed to by the rvalue reference, such that a rvalue reference is returned to the object? Also, why is the `remove_reference<T>` part required?

The tutorial also writes

> This move() gives its target the value of its argument, but is not
>   obliged to preserve the value of its source. So, for a vector, move()
>   could reasonably be expected to leave its argument as a zero-capacity
>   vector to avoid having to copy all the elements. In other words, move
>   is a potentially destructive read.

but then it is said that

> The move function really does very little work. All move does is
>   accept either an lvalue or rvalue argument, and return it as an rvalue
>   without triggering a copy construction.

Should this be understood as, the std::move() could first "empty" the object (in this case a std::vector) and thereafter return the object as an rvalue (according to the C++ specification)? But, that the official std::move() does exactly as specified in the latter quote?

And why is it said that std::move() returns a rvalue, when it returns a rvalue reference?

Comment: `move` turns an expression of type `U` into an rvalue of type `U` (specifically, an xvalue). Because of the type deduction rules, `T` may be deduced either as `U` or as `U&` (depending on whether the expression is an rvalue or an lvalue), so you need the `remove_reference` in the code.

Comment: You're reading a paper from 2006, which uses a language which is not C++11. Look at the definition of `std::move` in a real C++11 implementation.

Comment: You're also confusing value categories (rvalue) with types (rvalue reference). `std::move` returns an rvalue (xvalue) that is of type rvalue reference to `T`.

Comment: @Barry: The type of a value is never a reference. The correct statement is that `move` returns an xvalue of type `remove_reference_t<T>`

Comment: *The parameter is a type T rvalue reference* [it's not](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: @KerrekSB You're right. Sometimes I think C++ is so easy.

Answer (score 10):

> The code for std::move() as stated here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html#Move_Semantics.

That was the proposed code in **2006**. Before move semantics was part of C++. That's not how `std::move` is implemented in C++, because the language changed **significantly** between 2006 and 2011. Look at a modern implementation if you want to understand `std::move`, rather than understand some old proposal that describes something similar but different.

> Why does this code return a rvalue reference?

Because that's the entire purpose of `std::move`. Take an argument and cast it to an rvalue.

Asking why it does that is like asking why `make_pair` returns a `pair`.

> The parameter is a type T rvalue reference.

Actually it's a "forwarding reference", which means it might be an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference.

> Does `a` evaluate to the object pointed to by the rvalue reference, such that a rvalue reference is returned to the object?

Yes, that's how references work.

> Also, why is the `remove_reference<T>` part required?

Because if `std::move` is called with an lvalue then `T` will be deduced  to an lvalue reference type, such as `int&`. To ensure the return type is `int&&` you first need to remove the lvalue reference to get `int`, then add `&&` to get an rvalue reference, `int&&`.

Comment: Thanks, this really clarifies things for me.

Comment: Just to be 100% certain, 'a' evaluate to the object - which is a temporary object - and to this temporary object an rvalue reference is returned?

Comment: Not necessarily a temporary, the reference `a` is bound to whatever argument you call `std::move` with. If I do `int i=0; std::move(i);` then it's not bound to a temporary.  Read https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers to understand "forwarding references" (previously known as "universal references")

Comment: I mean the expression "a" results in a temporary object, right?

Comment: No, that's not right. `a` is the function parameter, which is a reference, which is bound to the argument passed to the function. There are no temporaries involved.

Comment: I thoroughly recommend that you read https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers and http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html because they explain the whole topic properly. It's better to understand rvalue references properly before trying to understand `std::move` or how they apply to specific situations.

Answer (score 1):

`std::move` can be thought of as a glorified cast. All it does it converts the type of it's argument (an object or a result of an expression) into so-called `xvalue`. It does so by returning an rvalue reference to it.

It also takes care of the fact that deduced type of the argument might be an lvalue, in which cast T becomes really an lvalue reference - this is why it has to remove reference from T to get the 'real' type of the argument.

That's it. It doesn't actually move anything, clean up objects or any of the sorts. The actual object modification is done by corresponding move constructor or assingment operator.

Comment: It's not really a "temporary". Temporaries are prvalues, whereas `move` creates an xvalue.

Comment: Hm, this is all quite confuddled still. The object isn't "translated" (it's the same object!), the *value* is -- it's translated from whatever it was to an xvalue. Moreover, objects, and values, are never references, so "remove reference on the fly" doesn't really mean anything useful.

Comment: @KerrekSB, any better?

Comment: Hm, I don't know. It's still a bit of a dance around the sticky pudding. I think Jon Wakely's answer says it all clearly and correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
void f(const my_type&);
void f(my_type&&);
my_type m;
f(m);           // calls f(const my_type&)
f(std::move(m); // calls f(my_type&&)
```

The only thing that the call to `std::move` does is ensure that the type of the argument to `f` is an rvalue reference. It's up to `f` what to do with that reference once it has it.

You could do the same thing with a cast:

```
f(my_type&&(m));
```

but calling `std::move` is clearer and more consistent when used in more than one place.

Comment: Since an argument is an expression, the type of an argument can never be "reference". Rather, `move` ensures that the argument is an rvalue, thus being able to bind to the rvalue reference.

Comment: This is not formally correct. Like I said in my answer, move ensures the value is an ravlue (by returning it).

Comment: Quibbles aside, this answer makes the important point that `std::move` itself is trivial and fairly uninteresting, what it does is provide vocabulary for _enabling_ a move, not actually performing one.